# Creating a Login Page with Fortify and Livewire in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-fortify

I'm working on building a login page for my Laravel application using Fortify and Livewire. I've made some progress with the code, but I'm encountering some issues. Here's what I've done so far:

In `FortifyServiceProvider.php`, I've set the login view like this:

```php
Fortify::loginView(function () {
    return view('livewire.auth.login');
});
```

I also have a Livewire component called `Login.php` with the following code:

```php
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Livewire\Component;

class Login extends Component
{
    public $email = '';
    public $password = '';
    public $remember = false;

    protected $rules = [
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'password' => ['required'],
    ];

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.auth.login')->extends('layouts.guest');
    }
}
```

My `login.blade.php` file contains the login form, like this:

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
    @csrf
    <div>
        <label for="email" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 leading-5">
            Email address
        </label>

        <div class="mt-1 rounded-md shadow-sm">
            <input wire:model.lazy="email" id="email" name="email" type="email" required autofocus
                class="appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue focus:border-blue-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out sm:text-sm sm:leading-5 @error('email') border-red-300 text-red-900 placeholder-red-300 focus:border-red-300 focus:ring-red @enderror" />
        </div>

        @error('email')
        <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <div class="mt-6">
        <label for="password" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 leading-5">
            Password
        </label>

        <div class="mt-1 rounded-md shadow-sm">
            <input wire:model.lazy="password" id="password" type="password" required
                class="appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue focus:border-blue-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out sm:text-sm sm:leading-5 @error('password') border-red-300 text-red-900 placeholder-red-300 focus:border-red-300 focus:ring-red @enderror" />
        </div>

        @error('password')
        <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <div class="flex items-center justify-between mt-6">
        <div class="flex items-center">
            <input wire:model.lazy="remember" id="remember" type="checkbox"
                class="form-checkbox w-4 h-4 text-indigo-600 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" />
            <label for="remember" class="block ml-2 text-sm text-gray-900 leading-5">
                Remember
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="text-sm leading-5">
            <a href="{{ route('password.request') }}"
                class="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:underline transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                Forgot your password?
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mt-6">
        <span class="block w-full rounded-md shadow-sm">
            <button type="submit"
                class="flex justify-center w-full px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 border border-transparent rounded-md hover:bg-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-700 focus:ring-indigo active:bg-indigo-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                Sign in
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

I've also added a route in my `web.php` file:

```php
Route::get('/login', Login::class)->name('login');
```

The issue I'm facing is that when I click the "Submit" button, it doesn't perform the login action as expected. Instead, it redirects me back to the login page without any errors, even when I enter the correct credentials. Now, I'm trying to figure out how to handle the form submission and perform the login action. Can someone guide me on how to complete this login functionality using Fortify and Livewire?

Comment: So is it accessing the login route and hitting a middleware somewhere in between, which redirects any false attempts?